# Where's the annual Stack Exchange survey?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Stack Exchange used to have these nice annual surveys. They were really interesting, it gave us a good insight into how the network's demographics evolve.

There was one [in 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-annual-survey/), one [in 2011](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/come-here-often/), one [in 2012](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/hey-there-stranger/), and one [in 2013](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/who-are-you-take-the-2013-survey/).

Soooo... where's 2014?

Comment: The surveys were not really well designed. It takes a lot of work to design a survey and make the data useful.

Comment: @bluet I highly doubt it. All the others were posted during December, such a long delay probably means they prefered to skip the survey this year. (budget? too complex? dunno)

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it were made from scratch, I understand the budgetary and complexity restrictions. But StackExchange did have nice survey templates from the previous years. All it was needed were probably a few adjustements and it was good to go :) .

Comment: @Radu well, there were downsides and complaints about the way it works, maybe they decided to change it this year. Guess only time will tell... 6-8 weeks. :-)

Comment: 2 weeks passed, 4-6 weeks to go :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's fine... I guess. I won't cry myself to sleep because of it :)

Comment: Those are Stack *Overflow* surveys. Slightly different than the entire exchange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Update:** Survey is now [live and in the air](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/so2015)

It's coming!

We're finalizing questions now (and leaving more good questions on the cutting room floor than we'd like).

You should see an announcement for the survey much sooner than 6-8 weeks. Thanks for hanging in there.

Comment: Area 52 was promised to come "in matter of months". It was about four years ago. Just to explain my skepticism. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard What's that ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Four years?  You might be able to fudge by rounding up and say three years, but it'd be more accurate to say 2.5 years ish. http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51/5102#5102

Comment: @Radu what Adam said (was going to post this exact link), and sorry for being off by one year... still far from "but its almost certainly in the "months" time frame. It's not going to be weeks; **it's not going to be years**" - but it is years. I do not have anything against him or SE in general, it's their full right to take their time and delay projects.

Comment: @AdamDavis - I wouldn't hold your breath on Area 52. At least not if you want to live.

Comment: @samthebrand Ha! They/you are trying to re-invent stack exchange at this point... If you need more yak shavers, let me know.  Also, send a memo to Joel, *"Smart **and** gets things done"*, not ***or***. (Also, I'm teasing everyone here/stirring the pot, please take this as light humor, not whining, annoyance, or impatience...)

Comment: @AdamDavis we always need more yak shavers. Also bike shavers and yak shedders. Not positive the positions are publicly labeled that way: http://stackexchange.com/work-here

Comment: @sam if I might an off topic question... what exactly is your role in SE? It says "Community Developer" in the Team page on the portal but it doesn't really say very much. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're not very good at titles here. I do marketing & analytics. I also shave yaks.

Comment: Exactly 3 weeks, won't say "much sooner than 6-8" but guess better than actual 6-8 weeks. Thanks! :)